# Why am I unable to access an Angular route that does not have authgaurd

Tags: angular, url, routes

I am trying to access a page that does not have auth guard. However, I just get a blank page. Here is the code in routes.ts

```
{
    path: 'NewSignUp',
    component: NewSignUpComponent
},
```

Here is a code for a route protected url

```
{
    path: 'AttachmentComponent',
    component: AttachmentComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
```

The idea is so that new customers can access the new sign-up page and create a new account. This would mean they would need to access this page without being asked for authentication.

I have only added this code to the template for the new sign up page

```
  <label>This is the new forms page</label>
```

This only shows once I have logged in which is of no use.

Comment: Your code seems correct to me, so your problem must be elsewhere. You may need to show all your routes. Maybe you have a redirect somewhere that prevents you to land on that route. Does it work if you remove the `AuthGuard` from the `canActivate` property?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the code below in the app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```